# Get this Troll Program working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Scenario :**

- Attempted to create this troll **'guessing game program'**.
- It prompts the user to guess a number between 1-10, and the user will
  get it wrong each time until they guess all numbers, frustrated, I
  tell them to guess one last time, upon this attempt, it says your
  answer was right!

**Code** - I am new at JS so I have not really gone into DOM manipulation and the code for some reason does not work.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Guessing Game</title>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var numset = 0;
    var guess = numset + 1;
    var max = numset >= 11;

    while (guess !== max) {
        prompt("I am guessing a number between 1-10, let's see if you can guess it!"); 

    } else {
        alert("You Won! Number of guesses: 11")
    }



</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Todo :**

- Please correct this
- or Suggest any better approach, i am open to options.

Thank You.

Comment: `guess` will **always** be `1` ... `max` will **always** be `false` - therefore, since guess will never be the same as max, the loop will forever run ... note, the while loop runs code within the while loop, the code before the while loop is run just once, before the while loop runs at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use a `Set` of numbers between 1 and 10, prompt for a number and remove it from the set until the set is empty, and then display the total number of guesses.

Note that because the program uses `prompt`, it will *block* the user's browser - consider using something less user-unfriendly, like an `input` and a button / enter listener, if at all possible.

```js
// Set of numbers from 1 to 10:
const numSet = new Set(Array.from(
  { length: 10 },
  (_, i) => i + 1
));
let guesses = 1; // to account for the final guess at the end
while(numSet.size > 0) {
  const guessed = prompt("I am guessing a number between 1-10, let's see if you can guess it!");
  numSet.delete(Number(guessed));
  guesses++;
}
prompt("I am guessing a number between 1-10, let's see if you can guess it!");
alert("You Won! Number of guesses: " + guesses)
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be 11 guesses? Because you forget to count the last prompt

Comment: Ah, you're right, the count should be initialized to 1, not 0, to account for the final one